# Disabling function in wordpress child theme

Tags: wordpress

How to disable ;

```
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
```

in wordpress parent theme's functions.php from the child theme ?
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

This will remove support and Use in your Child Theme's functions.php(if child theme activate otherwise put in parent theme function.php)

```
<?php
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_featured_images_from_child_theme', 11 ); 

function remove_featured_images_from_child_theme() {

    // This will remove support
    remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
    remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
    remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
}
?>
```